# Como obter o resultado de um teste assertEquals do JUnit e por em uma variável tipo String?

Tags: java, testes, junit

Estou com um caso de teste do JUnit para testar uma classe simples. A classe a ser testada contém apenas um método "sum" que soma dois números. Para testar se está correto, uso o seguinte método: `Assert.assertEquals(2, meu_objeto.sum(1, 2));` 
O resultado aparece em uma aba do JUnit no eclipse, em uma parte chamada Failure Trace. A mensagem diz: `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<2> but was:<3>`
É possível pegar essa mensagem e colocar dentro de uma variável tipo String?

Comment: tenta capturar com try/catch

Comment: Já tentei, @user5978. Não consigo obter nenhum resultado com isso.

Comment: http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/AssertionFailedError.html. Aparentemente há um método: getMessage, tenta ele, se é que já não tentou.

Comment: O JUnit pode ser estendido de algumas maneiras, se a sua necessidade valer o empenho... Mas de repente há alternativas mais simples. Para que você precisa pegar esta mensagem em uma string?

Comment: user5978, não consegui usar getMessage. @Caffé eu preciso fazer um sistema de avaliação de classes usando JUnit, e preciso que essa mensagem apareça em uma janela de notificação para o usuário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception{
        String assertionError = null;
        try {
            Assert.assertEquals(2,3);
        }
        catch (AssertionError ae) {
            assertionError = ae.toString();
        }
        System.out.println(assertionError);

    }
```

Consegui a resposta no StackOverFlow em inglês, respondida por um usuário chamado 'Unknown'. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863515/how-to-get-an-output-from-junit-assertequals-method-and-put-it-into-a-variable/36863950#36863950